# Can I publish my dotnet core 3.0 application for Raspbian operation system with arm 32 bit architecture?

Tags: .net-core, raspberry-pi, publish, raspbian

I am building a dotnet core console application of version 3.0.
I want to publish this application to run on Raspberry Pi that has arm 32 bit architecture. The OS installed on Raspberry Pi is Raspbian.

How can I achieve the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to this question myself. We can publish the project for Linux ARM 32 bit architecture from the command prompt. The command is :

```
publish <Project-Name> -r linux-arm
```

linux-arm is RID for Linux ARM 32-bit architecture.